# c++ quadratic equation not working properly for a code checker

Tags: c++

I am submitting code to my university's tester, the code for me works thoroughly for the the test cases I provided.

The checker tells there are some test cases that can't pass, I am testing in visual studio, and that's exactly compatible with the online judge compiler.

The problem description: 
input : Contains 3 integer numbers: a,b,c (|a,b,c|<=1000).
output; The number of the equation's roots, then all roots in an ascending order. If you cannot do this, output "-1".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int a, b, c, delta;
    double x1, x2, x;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    delta = ((b*b) - (4 * a * c));
    if (a == 0) {
        if (b != 0) {
            x = (-(c)*1.0 / (b));
            cout << 1 << " " << x;
        }
        else
            cout << "-1";
    }
    else
        if (delta > 0)
        {
            x1 = ((-(b + sqrt(delta))*1.0) / (2 * a));
            x2 = ((-(b - sqrt(delta))*1.0) / (2 * a));
            if (x1 <= x2) {
                cout << 2 << " " << x1 << " " << x2;
            }
            else 
                cout << 2 << " " << x2 << " " << x1;

        }
        else if (delta == 0)
        {
            x = (-(b)*1.0 / (2 * a));
            cout << 1 << " " << x;
        }
        else
            cout << "-1";
    return 0;
}
```

I can't find any test case that fails my program, please if you can find some test cases, hints whatever I am just stuck at the problem. Thanks

Comment: Can you at least explain in short what the code does? and/or provide a couple of test case examples (input/output)?

Comment: Would it be practical to load input.txt? How many lines does it have?

Comment: @DimChtz, yes, the code is about a c++ implementation of the quadratic equation, the inputs are a, b, c, the coefficients, the output is the solution or -1 for no solutions. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `int` variables? Your code would fail for, say, `a = 1.5`.

Comment: @Adrian, actually, the problem states that the inputs are integers

Comment: OK - just asking. However, in `delta = ((b * b) - (4 * a * c))` the multiplications are performed as `int` before the subtraction promotes to `double`, so what if the products are greater than `INT_MAX`?

Comment: If the target machine supports a 32-bit `int` (fairly common in practice, including on a lot of windows boxes) then a value of `b` entered of `100000` will cause `b*b` to overflow.   That causes undefined behaviour - and, odds are, if there is a test case which enters such a value, that test case will not produce the required results.

Comment: @Peter, that's a great note, though, the problem states that |a,b,c| <= 1000

Comment: Presumably `-1` is the expected output if a solution cannot be found (`a=b=0` or `delta` negative)? Could there be a problem with rounding/default-precision of outputting the `x`/`x1`/`x2` values making what you produce and what they expect not quite match? (e.g. `1.999999` vs. `2` or `2.0` vs `2`)

Comment: Do you have example test cases? Do you know if at least one test case passes the test? Is it possible that all test cases are wrong because you have one whitespace or a newline to much? Maybe a newline is missing at the end.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, actually I tested with manually with differents test cases, here is the thing, the checker hides test cases, it says wrong for case n.

Comment: I think your problem is the `delta==0` case. You're outputting `1` and a root; the correct answer is the same root twice. E.g. `x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0` has a repeated root `-1`, but you produce `1 -1`

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of `x1` and `x2`

Comment: @Albjenow, they demand the two solutions to be in an ascending order

Comment: @Papa - I'm not a mindreader, and can't be aware of constraints before you provide them.   Also, consider what happens if input contains `1.0` as one the value of `a` - that is an integral value, but will prevent `b` and `c` being read as `int`s.   Also, consider what happens if negative values are entered - the output values may not be ascending (in magnitude)

Comment: Does at least one test case pass the test? _"it says wrong for case n"_ does this n change?

Comment: @Papa You also don't line-terminate the output (`... << endl`) which _might_ break their checker. But the repeated root error is probably the most likely.

Comment: Please provide the exact assignment text

Comment: @ThomasSablik, i have included the problem description. the example output is described as follows; intput; 1 -8 15  output 2 3 5

Comment: @TripeHound, actually I thought of that, and asked our tutor, her only answer was the problem is clearly defined!

Comment: @Papa Which point are you referring to? An input of `1 2 1` gives the wrong answer (`1 -1`) instead of `-1 -1`

Comment: @TripeHound, input 1 -2 1 gives right output 1 -1 (1 refers to the number of soluttions), please get back to the problem description above that I have include the formal problem statement by our online judge.

Comment: @Papa "_please get back to the problem description above_" Wasn't there when I replied! One could argue that the correct answer in that case is `2 -1 -1`. Other possibilities: might they want the output on separate lines? You say "_The checker tells there are some test cases that can't pass_"... does it _explicitly_ say that some of the test cases _do_ pass (in which case it could be overflow etc. for _specific_ inputs that's the problem). If it doesn't, it could be that _all_ test cases are failing (which would imply something common to _all_ inputs, like not being on separate lines).

Comment: @TripeHound, actually, it mentions some tests passed. No, output in the same line with space, and first output number is about the number of solutions otherwise -1

Comment: _No, output in the same line with space_ You should try to add a newline or space at the end of your output line. If they write all test cases to the same output file the first number of the second test case is next to the last number of the first test case. TC1: 1 2 1, TC2: 1 - 8 15, outputfile: 2 -12 3 5 instead of 2 -1 2 3 5

Comment: @Papa "_output in the same line with space_" THAT isn't mentioned in what you edited into the question. As others have said, without the EXACT requirements, we're only guessing at what might be wrong.

Comment: @TripeHound, that wasn t stated, it s just an image of the input output

Comment: Are you supposed to provide imaginary solutions? Which cases does it fail on? We NEED more info.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199785/discussion-on-question-by-papa-c-quadratic-equation-not-working-properly-for-a).

Answer (score 2):

> the example output is described as follows; intput: 1 -8 15 output: 2 3 5

If the input was `-1 8 -15`, this program would output `2 5 3`, while the two solutions are requested to be printed in ascending order. So you need to sort them before printing. Also I'd add a newline to every output statement.

***-edit-***

Without knowing the exact format required and the numbers in the failing tests, we can only speculate on how to modify the posted program. Some changes, though, could be beneficial.

**I/O**

There isn't any check of the input. On-line judges usually give well defined input, but you can always add some test.

```
cin >> a >> b >> c;
if (!cin)
    cout << "-1\n";
```

I already mentioned the newline at the end of the line, another (unknown) requirement could be a particular precision of the outputted numbers (in fixed or scientific format).

In the comments I also pointed out the particular case of `-0.0` or (`-0`), which while beeing a perfectly valid floating point value, could be for some reason rejected by the tester. Unlikely, but possible. So you could write the first case like this:

```
if (a == 0)
{
    if (b != 0)
    {
        if ( c == 0 )
            x = 0.0;
        else
            x = double(-c) / b;

        cout << "1 " << x << '\n';
    }
    else
        cout << "-1\n";
}
```

**precision and corner cases**

In the unlikely (given the ranges of the input values) case that you are running into precision issues, you could choose other formulas (see e.g. [numerically stable algorithm for solving the quadratic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866331/numerically-stable-algorithm-for-solving-the-quadratic-equation-when-a-is-very)).

```
else if (delta > 0)
{
    if ( c == 0 )
    {
        x1 = 0.0;
        x2 = double(-b) / a;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( b > 0 )
            x1 = -0.5 * (b + std::sqrt(delta)) / a;
        else
            x1 = -0.5 * (b - std::sqrt(delta)) / a;
        x2 = c / (a * x1);
    }

    if (x1 > x2)
        cout << "2 " << x2 << " " << x1 << '\n';
    else
        cout << "2 " << x1 << " " << x2 << '\n';
}
```

The last part really boils down to how to consider two coincident solutions.

```
else if (delta == 0)
{
    if ( b == 0 )
        x = 0.0;
    else
        x = -0.5 * b / a;

    cout << "1 " << x << '\n';
    // Assuming they don't require ("all the roots")
    // cout << "2 " << x << ' ' << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I did update the code, and still stops at test 5 fails.

Comment: @Bon is there another way of printing 0 insteadof -0 other than the way you did it.

Comment: @Papa Well, you can always use a normal `if` instead of the conditional operator. If that is problem.

Comment: I edited the code that prints 0 instead of -0, still doesn't pass the test 5, I mean the same as the one you gave.

Comment: @Papa It would help to know what that test is about, if it's a precision or formatting issue, the double solutions problem or some corner case. Without any further data, we (me, at least) can't really help.

Comment: the checker doesn't provide it. In any case, thanks.

Comment: Without having a clearly defined output format, there is no way to verify the correctness of your program. Your professor needs to explain the format further.

Answer (score 0):

The problems would likely lie in the realm of int to double conversion.

To debug this, you need to separate out your operations into distinct lines the debugger can stop on. For instance the expression `-(c*1.0)` is better expressed as `(double)-c`. It at least makes it clearer and utilizes a negation (free) and cast (more precise [linguistically] than multiplication by 1.0).

So for instance, your code would become something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int mainC(int argc , char** argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int a, b, c, delta;

    double x1, x2, x;

    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    delta = ((b*b) - (4 * a * c));

    if (a == 0) {
        if (b != 0) {
///            x = (-(c*1.0) / (b));
            /// separate the operation and avoid multiplication and implicit casts
            x = ((double)-c);
            x /= (double)b;
            cout << 1 << " " << x;
        }
        else
            cout << "-1";
    }
    else
        if (delta > 0)
        {
///            x1 = ((-(b + sqrt(delta))*1.0) / (2 * a));
///            x2 = ((-(b - sqrt(delta))*1.0) / (2 * a));
            /// separate the operation and avoid multiplication and implicit casts
            // discriminant
            const double discrim = sqrt(delta);
            x = (double)-b;
            x1 = x + discrim;
            x2 = x - discrim;
            x1 /= (double)(2*a);
            x2 /= (double)(2*a);
            cout << 2 << " " << x1 << " " << x2;
        }
        else if (delta == 0)
        {
///            x = (-(b*1.0) / (2 * a));
            /// separate the operation and avoid multiplication and implicit casts
            x = (double)-b;
            x /= (double)(2*a);
            cout << 1 << " " << x;
        }
        else
            cout << "-1";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give us the exact wording of the assignment.

Comment: This is the format: Input:

Contains 3 integer numbers: a,b,c (|a,b,c|<=1000).

Output:

The number of the equation's roots, then all roots in an ascending order. If you cannot do this, output "-1". Example; input: 1 -8 15 output: 2 3 5

Comment: If reversing the order of output of x1 and x2 doesn't do it (using my code) then they're not giving us enough information. My code should work except for outputting two in ascending order, but that's a minor fix.

Answer (score -3):

I think default cout precision does not math to your problem. Try

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10);
```

or greater.
Also u can try use

```
std::cout << std::flush
```